# C# Invalid attempt to call depth when reader is closed

Tags: c#, sql

When I try to run the above code the first part which is load all the existing records works fine. But when I try to find a specific record by using the search box the following error box pops up: 
[image: Error Message!]

Any help would be appreciated. The code is given below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace DataBase
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string Connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBase"].ConnectionString;
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Load1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connection);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from tblClasses", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Load(reader);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = table;
        con.Close();
    }

    private void Search1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connection))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from tblClasses where Teacher_ID = '" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            BindingSource Source = new BindingSource();
            Source.DataSource = reader;

            dataGridView2.DataSource = Source;

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Don't use a reader as a datasource, use a DataTable or similar like in the click event. It is going to close when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Also, are you familiar with SQL injection? It could be a good thing that this code doesn't work because a properly crafted value in textBox1 would own your database.

Comment: Yeah, I just started learning Sql about a week or so ago so I don't really know that much about SQL injection.

Comment: @Crowcoder I used the DataTable like you said the error doesn't pop up anymore, but I can't see the records in the DataGrid. Could you provide some code.

Comment: I would say there is no record for the teacher id you are using or the teacher id is a number, not a string. In SQL, numbers do not get surrounded with single quotes.

Comment: Thank you. I found the error. Now I feel like an idiot.

Comment: Well then you have just joined the club. Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is not totally correct but it might put a different slant on it.

```
con = new SqlConnection(Connection);
SqlCommand command;
string sql = ("select * from tblClasses");
command = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

con.Open();
command.ExecuteReader();
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Load(table);
dataGridView2.DataSource = table;
con.Close();
```